# How to put graph inside modal window?

Tags: javascript

I've got a modal window (div element set to `display: none;`), which appears, when user clicks on the trigger. Here is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/kh7447a2/. Also I've got a graph, plotted using Chart.js: https://jsfiddle.net/6ssyussw/. 
So my question is how to put this graph inside modal window and make this modal window pop up with graph on it? They both work nice separately, but when I put them together, modal window doesn't pop up or it pops up, but without graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have a working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/mun27he8/

I just created a new canvas element with id `myChart` and added it to the modal container:

```
  // Add Canvas
  canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.id = "myChart";
  canvas.width = 400;
  canvas.height = 400;
  contentHolder.appendChild(canvas);
```

Then I set all the chart JS code to run when you click the button.